# Possible to change "Saved Password" style in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I made a login page which looks like this:

[image: default login]

but when I save my login data in Firefox it looks like this:

[image: saved login data]

so can I and if yes how can I get rid of this yellow-ish tint and maybe make my own effect? I found some posts where it was said that it can be changed by using `-webkit-autofill` pseudoclass but that didn't work for me.

Code snippet:

```css
button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #0060df;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 231);
}

.text-input {
    height: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #5a5a5c;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: #474749 !important;
    color: rgb(230, 230, 231) !important;
}

#login-form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #323234;
}
```

```html
<div id="login-form">
  <input type="text" class="text-input" id="name-input" placeholder="Name"/>
  <input type="password" class="text-input" id="password-input" placeholder="Password"/>
  <button id="login-button">Login</button>
</div>
```

As you can see adding !important doesn't help aswell (if it is possible to test that in the snippet).

Regards
Blakk

Comment: From a UX standpoint, this is a bad idea. Users understand what the yellow color means -- why change it and confuse them?

Comment: I see you point but in this case it's just an admin login so there's only one or few person who will use this. Also the inputs already look different and users will understand that this is the saved login data if they see their username. It really doesn't look good because the border color changes to blue when focused. https://i.imgur.com/ZZVcdrZ.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox [doesn't support the :autofill pseudo-class as of 68](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill), you can subscribe to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740979 to track the status of implementation.

https://paul.kinlan.me/detecting-when-autofill-happens/ describes a workaround, which allows you to detect when autofill happens and swap in a new  element to replace the existing one, copying over the autofilled data.